# Insert into a child table for every row in a parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

My DB looks like this

```
tblAudits
PK AuditID
AuditStatus nvarchar(50)

tblQuestionDefs
PK QuestionID

tblAuditAnswers
PK AnswerID
FK AuditID
FK QuestionID
```

I've recently added some new questions to the audits and I want to add an answer record for each new question to all active audits.  What is the best way to do this in SQL?  I know I can use *cursors* or *loops*, but those are both very slow AFAIK.  Any set-based way to do it?

Here's the cursor based code

```
declare
    @AuditID int

declare AuditsCursor cursor fast_forward for
    select AuditID from tblAudits where AuditStatus='Issued' or AuditStatus='Pending' order by AuditID desc

open AuditsCursor
fetch next from AuditsCursor
into @AuditID

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    insert into tblAuditAnswers (AuditID, QuestionID)
    select @AuditID as AuditID, QuestionID
    from tblQuestionDefs
    where QuestionID not in (
        select QuestionID from tblAuditAnswers where AuditID=@AuditID
    )

fetch next from AuditsCursor
into @AuditID
end

close AuditsCursor
deallocate AuditsCursor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert into tblAuditAnswers (AuditID, QuestionID)
select A.AuditID, QD.QuestionID
from tblAudits as A
  cross join tblQuestionDefs as QD
where (A.AuditStatus='Issued' or A.AuditStatus='Pending') and
        not exists (select *
                    from tblAuditAnswers as AA
                    where QD.QuestionID = AA.QuestionID and
                          A.AuditID = AA.AuditID)
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/123061/

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO tblAuditAnswers
            (AuditID,
             QuestionID)
SELECT A.AuditID,
       Q.QuestionID
FROM   tblAudits A
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT QuestionID
                   FROM   tblQuestionDefs
                   EXCEPT
                   SELECT QuestionID
                   FROM   tblAuditAnswers) Q
WHERE  A.AuditStatus IN ( 'Issued', 'Pending' )
```

Comment: +1 - Very nice answer. I don't know why I always forget `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT`

Comment: @Martin Smith Awesome!  Could you explain how the cross join knows to select only the QuestionIDs from tblAuditAnswers for the current audit (ie the A.AuditID)?

Comment: @just.another.programmer - You say you want to want to "add an answer record for each new question to all active audits." The derived table `Q` contains all new questions. (new being assumed to be ones in `tblQuestionDefs` where there is no corresponding entry yet in `tblAuditAnswers`). If that returns `X`  rows and there are `Y` rows returned by the query on `tblAudits` to find active audits then the cross join will return `X * Y` rows for every combination of the two results.

Comment: It seems it's only checking if the QuestionID exists in tblAuditAnswers at all, not if its in for that particular audit.  @Mikael Eriksson 's answer below seems to solve that.

Comment: @just.another.programmer - Yes that should be all that is needed if these are new questions - unless you have already been running your cursor code and done half an import?

Comment: @MartinSmith that's exactly the problem.  There's already a lot of answer data in the DB (this is a live site that's been running for a while).  I only wanted to add new questions, not produce the entire DB over again.  Thanks for the info on cross join, +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for cursors.

```
INSERT INTO tblAuditAnswers
    (AuditID, QuestionID)
SELECT
    A.AuditID, Q.QuestionID
FROM
    tblAudits A
    CROSS JOIN tblQuestionDefs Q
    LEFT JOIN tblAuditAnswers AA
        ON A.AuditID = AA.AuditID AND Q.QuestionID = AA.QuestionID
WHERE
    A.AuditStatus='Issued' OR A.AuditStatus='Pending' AND
    AA.AuditID IS NULL
ORDER BY
    A.AuditID DESC
```

If the question definitions are related to specific audit types, then you should also replace the CROSS JOIN by an INNER JOIN:

```
INNER JOIN tblQuestionDefs Q
    A.AuditTypeID = Q.AuditTypeID
```